# Binary file on Linux machine looking for libraries in /lib by default

Tags: linux, ld

On my UNIX machine I observed that the binaries are looking for the dependent shared libraries in '`/lib`' directory by default even though the '/lib' directory is not configured in `'PATH`' and '`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`' variables.

I the below see that the library 'libssl.so.4' is found from the '/lib' directory.

```
bash-3.00$ ldd openssl
        /lib/libcwait.so (0x00f86000)
        libssl.so.4 => /lib/libssl.so.4 (0x00408000)
```

My 'PATH' and 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' are below:

```
bash-3.00$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
:/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/client32/lib:

bash-3.00$ echo $PATH
/opt/pure/releases/purify.hp.2003a.06.15.FixPack.0214/cache/opt/star-ncf-prod/ep_patch/usr/lib:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/ucb:/etc:/bin:.:/opt/ccm71/bin:/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/client32/bin:/opt/tools/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

Please let mw know if the binaries refer to '/lib' directory by default ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [ld.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html), [ldd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) and [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) man pages and [Drepper's paper: *How To Write Shared Libraries*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

You'll see that "If a library dependency does not contain a slash, then it is searched
       for" *at last* in `/lib` then `/usr/lib`

These two directories are builtin, i.e. wired in the code of the dynamic linker, e.g. of `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` on my Debian system (I guess -but I am not sure- that on my Debian `/lib64/` is also wired in).

Answer (score 0):

In order for an executable to find the required libraries to link with during run time, one must configure the system so that the libraries can be found. Methods available: (Do at least one of the following)

Add library directories to be included during dynamic linking to the file /etc/ld.so.conf

Sample: /etc/ld.so.conf
    `/usr/X11R6/lib
    /usr/lib
    ...
    /usr/lib/sane
    /usr/lib/mysql
    /opt/lib`
Add the library path to this file and then execute the command (as root) ldconfig to configure the linker run-time bindings. 
You can use the "-f file-name" flag to reference another configuration file if you are developing for different environments. 
See man page for command ldconfig

OR

Add specified directory to library cache: (as root) 
ldconfig -n /opt/lib 
Where /opt/lib is the directory containing your library libctest.so 
(When developing and just adding your current directory: ldconfig -n . Link with -L.)
This will NOT permanently configure the system to include this directory. The information will be lost upon system reboot.

OR

Specify the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to the directory paths containing the shared object library. This will specify to the run time loader that the library paths will be used during execution to resolve dependencies. 
(Linux/Solaris: LD_LIBRARY_PATH, SGI: LD_LIBRARYN32_PATH, AIX: LIBPATH, Mac OS X: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, HP-UX: SHLIB_PATH)

Example (bash shell): export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH or add to your ~/.bashrc file:

```
`...
 if [ -d /opt/lib ];
 then
     LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
 fi
 ...
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
```

This instructs the run time loader to look in the path described by the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH, to resolve shared libraries. This will include the path /opt/lib.
Library paths used should conform to the "Linux Standard Base" directory structure.